# Кросскомпиляция модуля helloworld

Tags: linux, c, makefile, кросс-компиляция, модули

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь собрать модуль **helloworld** под другую машину. Хост **x86_64**, таргет **armhf**.
Установил кросскомилятор **/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc**, скачал исходники ядра под данную машину **~/projects/linux-3.4.113/**
Пытаюсь собрать (пробовал через makefile, переменные, но поскольку ничего не получилось, пытаюсь уже в лоб):
*/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I~/projects/linux-3.4.113/ -c ./helloworld.c*

(и много всяких мелких вариаций похожей команды)
На что раз за разом получаю ругань о том, что **linux/modules.h** не найден.
Может кто объяснить что я делаю не так, и как надо правильно?
Исходный код helloworld:

```
/*
 *  hello-1.c - The simplest kernel module.
 */
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");

    /*
     * A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded.
     */
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

Содержимое Makefile, которым пытался собирать модуль:

```
CC := g++
TOOLCHAIN := arm-linux-gnueabihf
PT :=
CFL := -Wextra -std=c++11
TPATH := /usr/bin/
LPATH := /usr/$(TOOLCHAIN)/
ARCH := arm
all: helloworld.c
    $(TPATH)$(TOOLCHAIN)-$(CC) $(CFL) $(ARCH) -o helloworld.c
```

Comment: может `-I~/projects/linux-3.4.113/include` по крайней мере пути к хеадерам ядра идут начиная с этой точки.

Comment: Пробовал и такой вариант. Пробовал даже в коде модуля написать "путь до хидера", он их подхватывал, но разумеется дальше шли проблемы с тем, что он не находил вложенные хидеры.

Comment: там надо смотреть чего не хватает. например в обычном include в системе есть папка asm, которая то же из kernel-headers идет. соответственно она должна находится по указанному пути. но ее там нет, может потребоваться символические ссылки сделать. так же попробуйте взять пакет kernel-headers для нужного вам ядра и развернуть его куда нибудь отдельно

Comment: Да, в этой папке нет asm. Она есть в /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include, ее я тоже пробовал через -I добавлять.

Comment: а в /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include есть своя папка linux ? если нет, то попробуйте в ней сделать символическую ссылку с именем linux указывающую на linux/include нужного ядра. и указывайте при сборке в -I именно ее.

Comment: папка linux там есть.

Comment: Собрать модуль ручками — это довольно нетривиальная задача... Даже если у тебя получится его скомпилировать, слинковать самостоятельно ты его почти наверняка не сможешь... Так что так ни кто не делает... Просто запиши обычный ядерный Makefile и собирай через него, как-то так: `make  M=$PWD -C ~/projects/linux-3.4.113/ ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`... Да, кроме самих исходников нужен будет конфиг ядра и подготовить дерево исходников для сборки модулей примерно так: `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc modules_prepare`

Comment: @Fat-Zer, прошу прощения, а можете подсказать содержимое Makefile-а? Просто, я изначально через него и пробовал, но что-то пошло не так (содержимое добавил в вопрос выше).

Плохо конечно, что я пока плохо понимаю написание этих команд для компиляции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Основные зависимости

Для сборки внешних модулей ядра обязательно надо иметь:

- Исходные кода ядра, крайне желательно точно той же версии, что и на запущенном ядре (достаточно будет заголовочные файлы ядра с `Makefile`'ами [содержимое пакета `linux-headers*` в большинстве пакетных дистрибутивов])
- Конфиг ядра под которое собираешь или максимально близкий.
- [Кросс-]компилятор, make и прочую dev-мишуру

### Типовая структура

```
.
├── hello.c
└── Kbuild
```

**hello.c**:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

int init_module(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello cruel world.\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye cruel world.\n");
}
```

**Kbuild** или **Makefile**, первое предпочтительнее. В простейшем случаее содержит **одну** строчку:

```
obj-m += hello.o
```

### Подготовка дерева исходников ядра

Далее подразумевается, что исходники ядра распакованы в `/tmp/linux`, префикс кросс компилятора `armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi`, а целевая архитектура `arm`.

Создайм config:

```
$ cd /tmp/linux
$ cp /path/to/my/kernel/config ./.config
```

Желательно сделать oldconfig и ответить на сотню другую вопросов, но  вполне хватит и silentoldconfig. Внимание на `-` в конце `CROSS_COMPILE` — это не ошибка, так и должно быть.

```
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi- silentoldconfig
```

Стоит проверить, что поддержка модулей в ядре включена:

```
$ grep CONFIG_MODULES .config
CONFIG_MODULES_USE_ELF_REL=y
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_MODULES_TREE_LOOKUP=y
```

Подготовка дерева для сборки модулей:

```
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi- modules_prepare
```

Перед кросс компиляцией настоятельно советую потренироваться и собрать `helloworld` для текущего нативного ядра, всё точно также, но не надо указывать `CROSS_COMPILE` и `ARCH`.

### Сборка модуля

```
$ cd /path/to/my/module
$ make -C /tmp/linux ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi- M=$PWD modules
```

make: вход в каталог «/tmp/linux»

```
  WARNING: Symbol version dump ./Module.symvers
           is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

  CC [M]  /tmp/hello-module/hello.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/hello-module/hello.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/hello-module/hello.ko
make: выход из каталога «/tmp/linux»

$ file hello.ko
hello.ko: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), BuildID[sha1]=16266c17567bf164e6fd4f48a52ecf477dad55cb, not stripped
```

Всё, как видно на выходе получен `hello.ko`.

Предупреждение про Module.symvers можно игнорировать покуда нет зависимостей от других модулей. Иначе нужно будет пересобрать модули самого ядра или разжиться данным файлом.

### К прочтению:

[Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)